# Include characters with accents and diereses within square root

Tags: symbols, accents

Could someone please let me know how to include the s-with-a-hat character (`\^{s}`) within a square root.  I hoped `$\sqrt{ \^{s} }$` would do the job.

Comment: this is unrelated to square root, you need hat rather than ^ in math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @karlkoeller 's answer - you can use `\text` and `\emph` in math mode. This may not get the italicized variable names quite right.  Clearly needs work for accents below the letter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\sqrt{\hat{s}}$ $\sqrt{\text{\emph{\"s}}}$ 
$\sqrt{\text{\emph{\v{s}}}}$ $\sqrt{\text{\emph{\c{s}}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `$\sqrt{\ddot{s}}$` to `$\sqrt{\text{\emph{\"s}}}$`, at least for situations that involve the second derivative with respect to time... The placement of the cedilla below the italic-s is much improved by loading either the `lmodern` package or the `fontenc` package with option `T1`, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. It could be only for the cedilla, but for hat, double dot and check accents, one should use `\hat{s}`, `\ddot{s}` and `\check{s}`. Note also that `$\sqrt{\text{\emph{\"s}}}$` would result in an upright s when in the statement of a theorem or anywhere italics is used.

Comment: @egreg I knew (and said) the `\emph` was a hack. Without knowing the OP's use cases I don't know whether that's a problem.

Answer (score 10):

Probably you are looking for the `\hat` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\sqrt{\hat{s}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great, thanks.  Only there are all sorts of other symbols I'd like to use within the square root sign, such as those listed here: (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes).  Do I have to find math mode equivalents of them all?

Comment: @JamesBejon Yes, you should look the math versions of these up, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/15925 .  The math versions work too when there are multiple accents on the same symbol.